# How to make markdown files in Git repositories indexable by search engines?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, github

If I google "@typescript-eslint no-invalid-void-type", the first search result will be **typescript-eslint/no-invalid-void-type.md at main - GitHub**, the [markdown file in @typescript-eslint repository](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-invalid-void-type.md). This location is pretty deep: `packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-invalid-void-type.md`.

However, if I google `@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions removeLastCharacter`, I'll get **No search result** (on my language), while this page is [exists](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-ES-Extensions/blob/master/CoreLibrary/Package/Documentation/Strings/removeLastCharacter.md) in directory `CoreLibrary/Package/Documentation/Strings/removeLastCharacter.md` of
[Yamato-Daiwa-ES-Extensions monorepository](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-ES-Extensions).

Which kind of magic allows **@typescript-eslint** documentation to be indexed by Google?

### Update before start bounty

Unfortunately, the current answer does not explaing why my markup documentaion does not appear in the search results, while similar documentation for **@typescript-eslint** is being indexed well.

Let the documentation for [**replaceArrayElementsByPredicates** function](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-ES-Extensions/blob/master/CoreLibrary/Package/Documentation/Arrays/replaceArrayElementsByPredicates/replaceArrayElementsByPredicates.md) will be the experimental sample.

First, I tried to use the suggested tool - Google Mobile Friendy Test . The result is "everyting fine":

[image]

[Sharable link](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly/result?id=R7qFjfmgDOiTA3zRdzPwIA)

The name of GitHub repository is "Yamato-Daiwa-ES-Extensions" (there are some limitations that is why I used the n-dashes). Try to search `Yamato-Daiwa-ES-Extensions replaceArrayElementsByPredicates`. Just one search result, and it is not the GitHub:

[image]

The npm name is [@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions). Try to search `yamato-daiwa/es-extensions replaceArrayElementsByPredicates`. Just one result again:

[image].

The search request is exact as possibe. The google did not indexed this page? I suppose, before to promoute my library, it's documentation must recieve some organic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is already crawlable and indexable. It is likely the case that Google is not seeing enough signals that it is important for certain queries yet.

I would focus on getting the word out about your (really great) set of tools so people begin sharing it thus earning you backlinks. These are the most fundamental indication of a web page's importance.

The TypeScript repository gets a lot of attention from Google because of its established user base and popularity. Deep pages like the example you provided rank for queries that already enjoy substantial search volume and that is why Google has indexed them.

Take a look at its backlink profile (I'm using [Ahrefs](https://ahrefs.com)).

### TypeScript ESLint - Backlink Overview

[image]

You can get there too by continuing to do what you do and providing value to the TypeScript community!

---

### What will people search to find your repository?

I also want to take a second to point out that since your repository is still fairly new, people won't be entering `Yamato-Daiwa-ES-Extensions replaceArrayElementsByPredicates` as their search query.

So you want to optimize the `readme.md` with the verbiage that they'll be using to search for what your repository is. I would write as much content as you can about what it does, who it is for, and how it provides value for TypeScript engineers/developers.

---

### Immediate actions you may take

I would recommend that you create a web page and on your canonical website with the `readme.md` content I mentioned and link to/from the GitHub repository and NPM page.

In addition to creating useful content for users, this also helps provide Google with an understanding of what your repository is.

Also, perhaps some blogs about your tools - guides do really great on search. With some additional content you'll be well on your way. Then I would just wait and see what happens.

I would not be worried about duplicate readme content, to me it becomes more accessible. Allow Google to prioritize which one to rank and when. In this case, a user's search history will probably carry a lot of weight in that decision.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and advices! Accept & upvote & reputation prize.

Answer (score 2):

Search bots will crawl and index everything they can read and consider of value.

Although it is an md file, it is embedded in an HTML page so that it can be crawled by search engines. You can use the [Google Mobile Friendy Test](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly/result?id=GIm0reTH88d3jKgdW_DauQ) application to check how Google sees this page.

[image]

It doesn't matter if a URL is deeper than others as there are other factors like internal/external linking, quality content, keywords used, etc. that will affect the page ranking.